# Display function in singlylinkedlist that accepts head of the linkedlist as a parameter

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I wish to create two linkedlists and write a display function that accepts head of either the first or the second linkedlist as a parameter i.e.(a function that accepts head1 of the first list or head2 of the second list).However,I'm getting a Null pointer Exception.

```
package com.main.addtwoele;

public class LinkedList {

    Node head1, head2;

    public void insert(Node head, int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        Node temp = head;
        head = newNode;
        newNode.next = temp;
    }
    public void display(Node head) {
        Node temp = head;
        System.out.println("---------------Linked List---------------");
        if (temp.next == null) {
            System.out.println("---Head node----");
            System.out.println(temp.data);
        }
        while (temp.next != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.data + "->");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println(temp.data);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.insert(list.head1, 50);
        list.insert(list.head1, 40);
        list.insert(list.head1, 30);
        list.insert(list.head2, 20);
        list.display(list.head1);
    }

}

Node class is as follows :-

package com.main.addtwoele;

public class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }

}

Exception encountered :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.main.addtwoele.LinkedList.display(LinkedList.java:19)
    at com.main.addtwoele.LinkedList.main(LinkedList.java:40)
```

Comment: [edit] your question and tag a language. [tag:java]?

Comment: The `insert` function is modifying the parameter and not the class member (`head = newNode;`). See: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40480)

Comment: Why do you have 2 heads? This may be a design flaw. Why not just have 2 separate `LinkedList` objects?

Comment: How can I write insert function to modify the class member?I don't wish to pass head1 or head2 as parameter in the insert function.

Comment: I have two heads because I want to add two numbers represented by two linkedlists.

Comment: Then you should have linked lists. Like this: https://ideone.com/ADpq8K

Comment: It worked !! Thanks for all your help !:) Saved my day.Although I'm still curious to know how to use two heads if need be.

Comment: If you really need two heads, there are ways to do it. One would be to put them in an array: https://ideone.com/gzt7Ox

Comment: What if I want to add contents of two linked lists and return the head node of resultant list.                                                                                                      
Node addTwoLists(Node head1, Node head2) { }.

Comment: Create a 3rd list. Loop through first list, call `list3.insert()` for each member of `list1`. Repeat for `list2`. Like this: https://ideone.com/ADpq8K

Comment: Thanks for all your help.Will definitely upvote your answers after I earn the reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is with the insert function. Java will pass a parameter by value, meaning if you change what the variable points to in the function, you will not change what it points to outside the function.

```
Node head1, head2;

public void insert(Node head, int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    Node temp = head;
    head = newNode;  // This is changing what the parameter points to!
                     // Not what the class member points to
    newNode.next = temp;
}
```

You say you want 2 heads in your linked list. I don't think you need that (2 separate linked lists would work), but to do this you can use an array of `Node` objects. This will also allow you to modify the head objects in the function:

```
Node [] heads = new Node[2];

// The head parameter is the index in the heads array 
public void insert(int head, int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.next = heads[head];
    heads[head] = newNode;  // Works since we are not modifying what the heads member var points to.
                            // Just modifying it's contents
}
```

Personally, I would just use a single head object. Then you don't have to pass it as a parameter:

```
Node head;

public void insert(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
}
```

If you want 2 lists, then create 2 `LinkedList` objects.

There is also a bug in the `display` function that would show up if `head` is `null`. So you should check for that.